# how to merge multiple csv files with ​different headers?

Tags: python, numpy

I have some image datasets and I want to convert them to CSV file by using np.savetxt, but I couldn't find any way to combine them to one csv file. When I combine dataset vectors with "np.array", [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dzdxz.png) It is being something like this. And when I try to merge multiple csv files, even they have different header names, they are combined in the same headers but I don't want it. Are there anyway to combine them or just save them as one file by np.savetxt?
(btw really sorry for my English and my question,I'm new at stackoverflow)

For example I have these two csv files ([enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grjfz.png),[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4vbe.png)) And I want something like this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxJ82.png)(but for multiple files
here is my code

```
while x!=y:
    img=Image.open(f"0_resized/{x}.jpg").convert("L")
    arr = np.array(img)
    shape = arr.shape
    flat_arr = arr.ravel()
    np.savetxt(f"{x}.csv",flat_arr,fmt="%d")
    x+=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating several .csv files and combining them, we can create a list with the images and save it to one .csv file. To do so, we can make some little modifications to your code, as shown bellow:

```
list_arrays = []

while x!=y:
  img=Image.open(f"0_resized/{x}.jpg").convert("L")
  arr = np.array(img)
  shape = arr.shape
  flat_arr = arr.ravel().tolist()
  list_arrays.append(flat_arr)
    
  x+=1
    
final_arrays = np.asarray(list_arrays)
np.savetxt("images.csv", final_arrays.T, delimiter=",")
```

In the code above, we created a list called **list_arrays** where we save the flat arrays created in the while loop. After reading all images and saving their flat version in our list, we can transform it in an array, using the np.asarray method.

The key point here is to save not the array, but the transposed array (**final_arrays.T**), which puts each image in a column.

Comment: I thought I can use list.append but as I mentioned It didn't work because I forgot to use transpose. Thanks a lot for the good explanation.